# Integrating given function within certain limits

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If $\int_{\pi/2}^{x} \sqrt{3-2\sin^2 t} dt + \int_{0}^{y}\cos t dt = 0 $, then $dy/dx$ at $ x=\pi$ and $y = \pi$ is?

I'm unable to compute the first integral. Please help!

Comment: Hint:  you were not asked to compute the integral.  Do you know any theorems about differentiating functions written as integrals?

Comment: Will it simply be the function that we are integrating?

Comment: Be careful:  you are differentiating with respect to x but one of the integrals has y = y(x) as a limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You have not been asked to compute the integral. However, a certain well-know theorem, the fundamental theorem of calculus might come in handy. What does invoking the theorem yield?

Note that you are differentiating with respect to $x$ whilst one of integrals has $y$ as a limit.

Comment: Will it be - $$\sqrt{3-2\sin^2 t} (\pi/2 ~ to ~ x) + \cos t (0 ~ to ~ y) $$